# Illustrator space around outline and removing shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, pathfinder, fill

I've used "//" and "\" to create this "W", and have made them into outlines, as I'm trying to give the different layers a colour, as well as having a white space where the lines touch and I would like to remove the top of the second "\".

I'm struggling with the white space at the moment and now I've added a stroke, the fill has decreased. Is there another way I could do this?

I've also tried to use my pen tool to remove the top of the "\" but when using "Path Finder" I cannot find an option to "Minus Forward". I'm a newbie so any advice would be lovely :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Draw a shape with the pen tool that you would like to remove. So in your case draw a shape around the top part of the backwards slash

[image: Draw shape around the part you would like to delete]

Make sure the object is below that blue slash in the layers panel.

Open the Pathfinder window in window - pathfinder. Select both objects and select **minus back** in the pathfinder options (Lower right option).

See example

[image: Example 1]

The final result will look like this.

[image]

For more examples check out this site: http://www.illustratortips.com/index.php/Instruction/Intermediate-Tips/how-to-use-the-illustrator-pathfinder-palette.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle this is by simply using the **Appearance Panel** to arrange things properly first.

I'll assume you've got a "Rounded COrner" effect and then a white stroke on the black areas....

[image]

Select the black shapes and click and drag the stroke **below** the fill on the Appearance panel. This will solve the "shapes get smaller when stroked" issue.

From there, it's a simply matter of selecting it all and choosing `Object > Expand Appearance`. Then choose `Object > Expand` (click ok with both fill and stroke checked). Now, click the `Merge` button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (not the menu).

This will get you here:

[image]

Simply use the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) to click the white areas and delete them.

[image]

[image]